# Reading a CSV file as Text File that performs Addition and Average

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, sum, average

```
import csv                                                          
with open('Annual_Budget.csv') as csvfile:

readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

Column_Sum = []
Third_Column_Avg = []
High_Value = []
Low_Value = []

for row in readCSV:
   Column_Sum = []
Third_Column_Avg = []
High_Value = []
Low_Value = []

Column_Sum.append(Column_Sum)
Third_Column_Avg.append(Third_Column_Avg)
High_Value.append(High_Value)
Low_Value.append(Low_Value)

print(Column_Sum)
print(Third_Column_Avg)
print(High_Value)
print(Low_Value)`
```

How to read a csv as a text file and for each row add up the all of the numeric columns, skipping any columns that cannot be perceived as numbers and displays the sum when it is completed. It must also display the average of all values in the third column. It must also display the highest value and lowest value from the second column and show which row these values appeared in. I put a mock annual budget in picture format so you can get the idea of what I am trying to accomplish.
[CSV SCREENSHOT EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLiH0.png)
Output: `[SUM OF ALL NUMERIC COLUMNS], [AVERAGE OF ALL VALUES IN THIRD COLUMN], [HIGHEST VALUE FROM SECOND COLUMN][LOWEST VALUE FROM SECOND COLUMN]`

Comment: Suggest you break down this task into components.  You are trying to do too much at once.  Try first reading the lines from the CSV and tokenizing them.  Then start with the math of adding them up.  Remember, that anything read from a CSV is taken in as a `String`, so you will have to convert known columns to `ints` or `floats`

Comment: I second Jeff. After you read/tokenize your data, you could do an `isdigit()` check on each item.

Answer (score 2):

With the pandas library (I made a file just like your screenshot) if you don't have this library just `pip install pandas`

then

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: my_file = pd.read_csv('stack.csv')

In [3]: my_file
Out[3]:
   anual budget    q2    q4
0            100  450    20
1            600  765    50
2            500  380    79
3            800  480   455
4           1100   65  4320
```

Anual budget, q2 and q4 sum

```
my_file['anual budget '].sum() 
my_file['q2'].sum() 
my_file['q4'].sum()
```

Average of third column

`my_file['q4'].mean()`

Min and max value of second column

```
my_file['q2'].max()
my_file['q2'].min()
```